# set new HTTPPassword in Lotus formula language

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I'm trying to retrieve the value of the HTTP password field for users with an specific password then the encrypted value is fine, if that password is found then change it to something else. It does change the password even is it doesn't match the encrypted value i have in the compare formula

Here is what I have so far

```
@If(@Compare(@GetDocField(@DocumentUniqueID;HTTPPassword);"7CCA9F186090ADEC4FA2A545B35F899A")
;@SetDocField(@DocumentUniqueID; "HTTPPassword"; "Newpassword");"");
SELECT @All
```

Any Help is greatly appreciated, this is for my work data security group. I need to change a bunch of compromised passwords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A much simpler formula would be

```
FIELD HTTPPassword := @If(HTTPPassword = "(7CCA9F186090ADEC4FA2A545B35F899A)"; @Password("NewPassword"); HttpPassword);
```

That said, writing code may not be the best way of doing this particular task. See [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HhlpzY14BX0) for an alternative.

Comment: Password- Hashes in Notes ALWAYS are encased in brackets... The above formula will NEVER match any password that was calculated using the `@Password` or `@HashPassword` value.. the correct value MIGHT be (7CCA9F186090ADEC4FA2A545B35F899A) instead...

Comment: Ahhh.,..  You're right!. I've never had reason to actually try to directly compare a password value before. I always assumed that the parens were just a display artifact, but they are part of the item value. Correcting the above formula.

Comment: I was able to change everyone's password to something secure before you posted your answer. I appreciate the replies